# How to resolve HTTP 404 status in SpringMVC?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

After trying to understand what am I doing wrong for almost the whole day I am giving up.
Seems like everything I found on stackoverflow I tried and yet I can't get it all working.
I have a simple SpringMVC+Maven+Hibernate tutorial set up and ready in eclipse, the only thing that is left is actually running it and seeing the result :( I keep getting HTTP 404 error whatever links I try.

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

[image: screen3]

Here is my setup:

**`web.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**`servlet-context.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd"> 

    <!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Map simple view name such as "test" into /WEB-INF/test.jsp -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Scan classpath for annotations (eg: @Service, @Repository etc) -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorial.pizzashop"/>

    <!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with 
       username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizzashop"/> 
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="discover"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
        <array>
            <value>com.tutorial.pizzashop</value>
        </array>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

**`index.jsp`**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Pizzashop</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>List of all Pizzas</h1>
    <ul>
        <c:forEach var="p" items="${pizzas}">
            <li>${p.id} - ${p.name} : ${p.price}</li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**`PizzaController.java`**

```
package com.tutorial.pizzashop;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class PizzaController {
    @Autowired
    private PizzaDAO pizzaDAO;

    /**
     * This handler method is invoked when http://localhost:8080/pizzashop is
     * requested. The method returns view name "index" which will be resolved
     * into /WEB-INF/index.jsp. See src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model model) {
        List<Pizza> pizzas = pizzaDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("pizzas", pizzas);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**`PizzaDAO.java`**

```
package com.tutorial.pizzashop;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public class PizzaDAO {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * @Transactional annotation below will trigger Spring Hibernate transaction
     *                manager to automatically create a hibernate session. See
     *                src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml
     */
    @Transactional
    public List<Pizza> findAll() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List pizzas = session.createQuery("from Pizza").list();
        return pizzas;
    }
}
```

**`Pizza.java`**

```
package com.tutorial.pizzashop;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PIZZAS")
public class Pizza {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private double price;

//getters and setters...
}
```

Tutorial I followed: http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/06/29/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-quick-start-from-scratch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, as it appears I didn't have any .java files in `scr/main/java` directory. Instead I had my .javas in `src/test/java` for some reason. What a stupid mistake. 
After I moved my .java files to `src/main/java`, compiled and packaged the .war, I moved my .war to Tomcat `webapps` directory, restarted the server and was able to run it:)

[image]

Comment: the ugly url name is due to the war package name not being `Pizzashop.war` but `Pizzashop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`. This can be corrected in pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

Your app doesn't appear to be deployed on the root context (/).

Try the URL:

> `http://localhost:8080/Pizzashop/`

The / that you refer to in your web.xml is the root of the context to which your app is deployed.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/pizzashop OR http://localhost:8080/Pizzashop does not work either :(

Comment: Capital P?  Try clicking on the second link down in your tomcat manager app.

Comment: No mapping found for Pizzashop or pizzashop in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'.
Clicking inside tomcat manager does not work either.

Comment: What about with a dash at the end: http://localhost:8080/Pizzashop  /  There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your configuration so I'm convinced it's to do with the context on which your app is deployed.  Have you checked your webapps directory in Tomcat?

Comment: hmm, when I open Tomcat `wtpwebapps` dir I see `/wtpwebapps/Pizzashop` and `/wtpwebapps/ROOT`, in `Pizzashop/WEB-INF/classes` I see nothing...

`/` is always added automatically to either `pizzashop` or `Pizzashop`

Comment: There's your problem.  How did you build the app?  You should have a .war file which you can place in the webapps directory.  This contains all your resources and code.  If you are using maven then try running MVN clean install and checking the target directory for the file.

Comment: guess you are right, something is missing in my pom.xml because `classes` dir is empty. `mvn package` does not add any .class files to folder either. Anyway .war file does not have classes that causes 404 errors. I shall post solution if I shall resolve it today.

Answer (score 1):

I have created spring mvc project with tomcat plugin in github, try this.

https://github.com/mohansaravanan/spring

https://github.com/mohansaravanan/spring/tree/master/springmvc-3.2.2